# linq for entities hide columns from model

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am using linq for entities to read and update data from a SQL server. This database is a Dynamic NAV database, and every time someone is changing a column in the database – my application need to be recompiled.

Is it possible to ignore or hide columns in the database from linq for entities, and still get update to work correctly? Let’s say there is 100 columns in a table, and that I am using on only 10, when I update a value – I want the remaining 90 values to stay in the row.

Answer (score 1):

You can just tell the people that add new columns to either

1. Allow null for newer columns
2. Or add a default constraint so a good default value is added automatically added for newer rows

Either of these will allow linq to work correctly

Comment: Good suggestions – your proposition would work for new columns, but it is not only new columns, some of these are **changed / deleted**.

Comment: `Walking on water and coding against a database schema are both easier when frozen`.  There is no automagic LINQ or otherwise solution one can implement if somebody modifies the primary key from a int to GUID

Comment: It is not the primary key that is modified, only column that my application doesn’t use. :)

Comment: If tables that you don't use in application are modified linq should work correctly.

Comment: you should drag tables from the db  in the linq designer and delete all other class properties that you don't plan to use. This way your view of table is much smaller. Now if these columns have default values or allow nulls. It would just work even if they change their types

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create a custom view in your database. If you want to be able to insert / update / delete from that view, you can create the appropriate triggers on the view. Linq will treat the view just like any other table.